# how can i have a list of icons in my android app;

Tags: java, android, eclipse

can any one suggest how can i have a list of icons like browser icon,email icon and contacts icon upon clicking on those it should lead to android browser,email and contacts apps respectively...right now i have done it, upon clicking buttons. Now i want icons(with image and text) instead of buttons...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#CustomButton

This will show you had to put the images you want in res/drawable/ and then load them up as buttons in your app.

Answer (score 1):

There is no widget icon.
You can do it yourself using a `LinearLayout` an `ImageView` and a `TextView`.

The xml should be something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/your_image"/>

  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/your_icon_text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hi thanks..i want image view similar in size of an icon and at corner of emulator screen...

Answer (score 0):

I thought you want to have  [**`ImageButton`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)  , clicking on that you want to open particular application/browser/contact list.

ImageButton - Displays a button with an image (instead of text) that can be pressed or clicked by the user

```
  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon/>
```

If you wants ImageButton with Background button then set `android:background` attribute, as below:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:background="@drawable/background_image"/>
```

Comment: hi can you plz let me know how to create ImageButton

Comment: hi Paresh i have used your code but got run time error...i written ImageButton code in my main.xml and i have saved a png icon image naming it as icon in res/drawable folder..and calling setonclicklistener(); method from my .java  program

Comment: hi thanks ...i have created using absolute layout and image buttons

Comment: @manju i think it is not preferrable to use "Absolute" layout, so please dont because in android, there are different kinds of resolutions available and by using absolute layout, you are fixing the size on the screen, so it may not look exactly on all the mobile screens

Comment: thanks a lot i was not knowing it before..Then can i use nested linear layout..i think linear layouts are not mobile dependent it works almost same on different mobile screens...

Comment: @manju have a look at http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html, and its best practice: you can take advantage of density independence in your application simply by making sure that your layouts specify all dimension values in density-independent pixels (dip or dp) or scale-independent pixels (sip or sp, for text only). For more informatio: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: hi Paresh i came to know the importance of dip and sip ..but i did not find solution to handle between portrait and landscape screens,there were about different screen sizes and densities but not given about portrait and landscape screens.

Comment: @manju first read the comment , which i have made on this question

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Image Button and set its property "Clickable=true" and do the required work on its click event listener

Answer (score 0):

If you want an image *and* text in your button, the way I do it is create a 9 patch, so I can define where the text will go using the padding and stretchable areas. Then follow the same instructions as for the Custom Button already mentioned, but use a standard button, not an Image Button.