# how can i have a list of icons in my android app;

Tags: java, android, eclipse

can any one suggest how can i have a list of icons like browser icon,email icon and contacts icon upon clicking on those it should lead to android browser,email and contacts apps respectively...right now i have done it, upon clicking buttons. Now i want icons(with image and text) instead of buttons.

Comment: answer is already at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183721/how-can-i-have-a-list-of-icons-in-my-android-app/4183760#4183760 , then why need to post 2 questions !!

Comment: As stated above, this question is an exact duplicate (even from the same user) and should be closed!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you just need to use something like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon" android:onClick="launchApp" />
    <TextView android:text="@string/icon_name" android:onClick="launchApp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and in your code you should have the corresponding method:

```
public void launchApp(View view) {
 // do something
}
```

Comment: hi i got it and can you please tell me how delete the questions asked twice in stackoverflow.com...